# Keep having to manually update Nokogiri on Mac OS X when running bundle update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler, nokogiri

A while ago I did a simple `bundle update` to get all my gems up to date on my Ruby on Rails project. However, at one point, I got an error about Nokogiri:

```
Building nokogiri using packaged libraries.

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/scott/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
Building nokogiri using packaged libraries.
-----
libiconv is missing.  please visit http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html for help with installing dependencies.
-----
```

I did some hunting and found [instructions to deal with this on the Nokogiri website](http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html). The following works after I manually installed libiconv according to their instructions:

```
gem update nokogiri -- --with-iconv-include=/usr/local/Cellar/libiconv/1.13.1/include --with-iconv-lib=/usr/local/Cellar/libiconv/1.13.1/lib
```

So afterwards I can run `bundle update` and all is good! The annoying thing is I have to go through this every time I run `bundle update` it seems as Nokogiri is updated somewhat frequently... Is there a way to automatically deal with this? I understand Nokogiri is a popular gem! A lot of people must be running into this issue.

***UPDATE***:
As requested by @Tim Moore, the output to my `bundle env` command:

```
scotts-mbp:ucode scott$ bundle env
Bundler 1.6.2
Ruby 2.1.2 (2014-05-08 patchlevel 95) [x86_64-darwin13.0]
Rubygems 2.2.2
rvm 1.25.28 (stable)
GEM_HOME /Users/scott/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@rails4
GEM_PATH /Users/scott/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@rails4:/Users/scott/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global
rubygems-bundler (1.4.4)

Bundler settings
  build.nokogiri
    Set for the current user (/Users/scott/.bundle/config): "\"--with-iconv-include=/usr/local/Cellar/libiconv/1.13.1/include --with-iconv-lib=/usr/local/Cellar/libiconv/1.13.1/lib\""


Gemfile
source 'http://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.1.2'

gem 'rails', '~> 4.1'

group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end

gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
gem 'coffee-rails'

gem 'uglifier'
gem 'foundation-rails'
gem 'compass-rails'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-rails-cdn'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'high_voltage'
gem 'devise'
gem 'cancan'
gem 'rolify'
gem 'liquid'
gem 'paperclip'
gem 'aws-sdk'
gem 'nokogiri'
gem 'jbuilder'
gem 'redcarpet'
gem 'kaminari'
gem 'ruby-saml-idp'

# Use unicorn as the web server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'


Gemfile.lock
GEM
  remote: http://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actionmailer (4.1.6)
      actionpack (= 4.1.6)
      actionview (= 4.1.6)
      mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
    actionpack (4.1.6)
      actionview (= 4.1.6)
      activesupport (= 4.1.6)
      rack (~> 1.5.2)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.2)
    actionview (4.1.6)
      activesupport (= 4.1.6)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
    activemodel (4.1.6)
      activesupport (= 4.1.6)
      builder (~> 3.1)
    activerecord (4.1.6)
      activemodel (= 4.1.6)
      activesupport (= 4.1.6)
      arel (~> 5.0.0)
    activesupport (4.1.6)
      i18n (~> 0.6, >= 0.6.9)
      json (~> 1.7, >= 1.7.7)
      minitest (~> 5.1)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
      tzinfo (~> 1.1)
    arel (5.0.1.20140414130214)
    aws-sdk (1.53.0)
      aws-sdk-v1 (= 1.53.0)
    aws-sdk-v1 (1.53.0)
      json (~> 1.4)
      nokogiri (>= 1.4.4)
    bcrypt (3.1.7)
    builder (3.2.2)
    cancan (1.6.10)
    chunky_png (1.3.1)
    climate_control (0.0.3)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
    cocaine (0.5.4)
      climate_control (>= 0.0.3, < 1.0)
    coffee-rails (4.0.1)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)
    coffee-script (2.3.0)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.8.0)
    compass (0.12.7)
      chunky_png (~> 1.2)
      fssm (>= 0.2.7)
      sass (~> 3.2.19)
    compass-rails (2.0.0)
      compass (>= 0.12.2)
    devise (3.3.0)
      bcrypt (~> 3.0)
      orm_adapter (~> 0.1)
      railties (>= 3.2.6, < 5)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
      warden (~> 1.2.3)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    execjs (2.2.1)
    foundation-rails (5.4.4.0)
      railties (>= 3.1.0)
      sass (>= 3.2.0)
    fssm (0.2.10)
    high_voltage (2.2.1)
    hike (1.2.3)
    i18n (0.6.11)
    jbuilder (2.1.3)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0, < 5)
      multi_json (~> 1.2)
    jquery-rails (3.1.2)
      railties (>= 3.0, < 5.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    jquery-rails-cdn (1.0.3)
      jquery-rails
    json (1.8.1)
    kaminari (0.16.1)
      actionpack (>= 3.0.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    liquid (2.6.1)
    macaddr (1.7.1)
      systemu (~> 2.6.2)
    mail (2.6.1)
      mime-types (>= 1.16, < 3)
    mime-types (2.3)
    mini_portile (0.6.0)
    minitest (5.4.1)
    multi_json (1.10.1)
    nokogiri (1.6.3.1)
      mini_portile (= 0.6.0)
    orm_adapter (0.5.0)
    paperclip (4.2.0)
      activemodel (>= 3.0.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
      cocaine (~> 0.5.3)
      mime-types
    pg (0.17.1)
    rack (1.5.2)
    rack-test (0.6.2)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (4.1.6)
      actionmailer (= 4.1.6)
      actionpack (= 4.1.6)
      actionview (= 4.1.6)
      activemodel (= 4.1.6)
      activerecord (= 4.1.6)
      activesupport (= 4.1.6)
      bundler (>= 1.3.0, < 2.0)
      railties (= 4.1.6)
      sprockets-rails (~> 2.0)
    rails_12factor (0.0.2)
      rails_serve_static_assets
      rails_stdout_logging
    rails_serve_static_assets (0.0.2)
    rails_stdout_logging (0.0.3)
    railties (4.1.6)
      actionpack (= 4.1.6)
      activesupport (= 4.1.6)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (>= 0.18.1, < 2.0)
    rake (10.3.2)
    redcarpet (3.1.2)
    rolify (3.4.1)
    ruby-saml-idp (0.3.2)
      uuid
    sass (3.2.19)
    sass-rails (4.0.3)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)
      sass (~> 3.2.0)
      sprockets (~> 2.8, <= 2.11.0)
      sprockets-rails (~> 2.0)
    sprockets (2.11.0)
      hike (~> 1.2)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      rack (~> 1.0)
      tilt (~> 1.1, != 1.3.0)
    sprockets-rails (2.1.4)
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
      sprockets (~> 2.8)
    sqlite3 (1.3.9)
    systemu (2.6.4)
    thor (0.19.1)
    thread_safe (0.3.4)
    tilt (1.4.1)
    turbolinks (2.3.0)
      coffee-rails
    tzinfo (1.2.2)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
    uglifier (2.5.3)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0)
      json (>= 1.8.0)
    uuid (2.3.7)
      macaddr (~> 1.0)
    warden (1.2.3)
      rack (>= 1.0)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  aws-sdk
  cancan
  coffee-rails
  compass-rails
  devise
  foundation-rails
  high_voltage
  jbuilder
  jquery-rails
  jquery-rails-cdn
  kaminari
  liquid
  nokogiri
  paperclip
  pg
  rails (~> 4.1)
  rails_12factor
  redcarpet
  rolify
  ruby-saml-idp
  sass-rails (~> 4.0.3)
  sqlite3
  turbolinks
  uglifier
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store the build setting in your Bundler config with:

```
bundle config build.nokogiri --with-iconv-include=/usr/local/Cellar/libiconv/1.13.1/include --with-iconv-lib=/usr/local/Cellar/libiconv/1.13.1/lib
```

See http://bundler.io/v1.6/man/bundle-config.1.html#BUILD-OPTIONS

Comment: Will this affect my deployment to Heroku? Will they see this as well or this will only be saved on my developing machine?

Comment: It will not affect Heroku. The configuration will be stored in `.bundle/config`, which you should not commit to git (put `.bundle` into `.gitignore` if it's not there already).

Comment: no it didn't work unfortunately @Tim Moore. I get the following error: `Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/scott/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby extconf.rb "--with-iconv-include=/usr/local/Cellar/libiconv/1.13.1/include --with-iconv-lib=/usr/local/Cellar/libiconv/1.13.1/lib"
Building nokogiri using packaged libraries.
-----
libiconv is missing.`

Comment: Can you update the question with the full error? Is that the right path to libiconv on your system? It will depend on what version you have installed from homebrew.

Comment: Please also include the output from `bundle env`.

Comment: yes that's the right path, I checked. And the `gem update` command I wrote in the original question (with the same paths) is what got it to work.